# W3C Document.parse() produces unwanted elements

Tags: java, xml, w3c

I just made up a simple XML file:

```
<main>
    <foo>
        <bar>1</bar>
        <bar>2</bar>
        <bar>3</bar>
    </foo>
</main>
```

I just tried to count the `bars` inside `foo` with this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FILE_FORMATTED);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList bars = doc.getElementsByTagName("foo").item(0).getChildNodes();

System.out.println(bars.getLength());
```

To my confusion i get `7` printed in the console. I then checked in the debugger what's inside the NodeList (screenshot appended). The parser apparently produces some Nodes from line breaks and whitespaces.

When I swapped the XML for a file without any formatting (and less readable), I got the expected result `3` printed. Here's the other XML:

```
<main><foo><bar>1</bar><bar>2</bar><bar>3</bar></foo></main>
```

I couldn't find anything about that behaviour. Is it not considered to be used on formatted XML files? Even `dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true)` didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling `setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace()` *before* `newDocumentBuilder()`? I wouldn't be surprised if that were the problem. (I wouldn't personally expect an already-created DocumentBuilder to be modified by a change to the factory that created it.)

Comment: They're not "non-existent elements", they're elements you didn't explicitly create. Whether or not whitespace matters depends on context, not content.

Comment: “I couldn't find anything about that behaviour.” 1. Look at org.w3c.dom javadoc. 2. Follow link in that javadoc to DOM Specification. 3. Read in [the section on Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) that “If there is no markup inside an element's content, the text is contained in a single object implementing the Text interface that is the only child of the element. If there is markup, it is parsed into the information items (elements, comments, etc.) and Text nodes that form the list of children of the element.”

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry actually I did call it before the creation I just pasted it wrong in the post. Updated it. still parsing the whitespaces as elements.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace-only text nodes in general are significant: consider

```
<para>A <adj>great</adj> <adj>green</adj> <noun>dragon</noun>.</para>
```

So if your application wants to treat whitespace as insignificant, you generally have to tell the parser explicitly to throw it away. Different XML APIs have different ways of doing this.